# Issue with Vagrant/Homestead setup (server requirements message)

Tags: install

I'm trying to set up a local dev environment for Craft. I've been following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfUqciZ91oU) So far, I've installed Composer, Vagrant, and Virtual Box. I have my `Homestead.yaml` file set up and going to `homestead.dev` is loading craft, but now I'm getting the following message about not meeting the server requirements and a blank list of requirements.

[image]

Any thoughts on what I'm missing, or where I could look? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some logs?

Comment: Definitely looks like a Craft bug to me.  Can you shoot an email to support@craftcms.com with a zip of `craft/storage/runtime/logs` so we can look into it? Going to go ahead and vote to close this as a bug.

Comment: 2017/04/05 18:49:26 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.503] Craft\HttpException in /home/vagrant/godandthegospel/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:800
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/godandthegospel/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(203): Craft\WebApp->_processInstallRequest()
#1 /home/vagrant/godandthegospel/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(185): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#2 /home/vagrant/godandthegospel/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#3 /home/vagrant/godandthegospel/site/index.php(19): require_once('/home/vagrant/g...')
#4 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/craft.css.map
---

Answer (score 0):

You can look at server logs and craft logs to begin with. You can also check the browser console.